# Unable to send or receive file using ssh2_scp_recv and ssh2_scp_send

Tags: php, security, ftp, ssh, file-transfer

Not sure what's wrong but I am unable to send or receive file using SSH.

I am using the following code

```
define('SSH_HOST', 'HOST');
define('SSH_USER', 'USER');
define('SSH_PASS', 'PASSWORD');
$connection = ssh2_connect(SSH_HOST, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, SSH_USER, SSH_PASS); 

$remoteFile = '/remote/absolute/path/file.ext';
$localFile = '/local/absolute/path/file.ext';

if(ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $remoteFile, $localFile)){
    echo("received");
}else{
    echo("NOT received");
}
```

Neither this nor `file_get_contents` function is working.
The strange thing is that I am able to get file stats by calling

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$statinfo = ssh2_sftp_stat($sftp, $remoteFile);
```

But unable to read file data.

Is there some special permission I have to set on either server?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious question, but you've checked to make sure you can actually scp the file from the remote server to the local machine from the command line, right?

Answer (score 4):

SCP and SFTP are different things. Probably, SCP is disabled on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  Easier to use and easier to diagnose problems with it due to its logging capabilities.  ie.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->put('filename.ext', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
echo $ssh->getLog();
?>
```